In the book "Zero to Monero", what does Square Brackers around a parameter passed to a Hash function denote?
I am reading the Book "Zero to Monero", 2nd Edition, Section 3.1 Page 26:


Generate random number $\alpha \in_{R} \mathbb{Z}_{l}$, and compute, for all $i \in(1, \ldots, d), \alpha J_{i}$.
Calculate the challenge,
$$
c=\mathcal{H}_{n}\left(\mathcal{J}, \mathcal{K},\left[\alpha J_{1}\right],\left[\alpha J_{2}\right], \ldots,\left[\alpha J_{d}\right]\right)
$$
Define the response $r=\alpha-c * k$.
Publish the signature $(c, r)$.


$αJ_n$ is a scalar $α$ and it multiplies an Elliptic Curve Base Point/Generator $J_n$. This multiplication results in an Elliptic Curve Point. So $αJ_n$ is an EC Point.
But why is it enclosed in Square Brackets while passing to the Hash function? Now $\mathcal{J}, \mathcal{K}$ are also EC Points, but they aren't enclosed in square brackets.
This isn't just in this one line but I see several places across the book where a computation which results in an elliptic curve point is enclosed in square brackets whereas a variable representing an EC Point like $\mathcal{K}$ isn't.
So is it just notation that whatever is in square brackets is a computation (i.e. multiplication of a point with a scalar, addition of 2 points etc.) or is there anything more to it?

Would it make sense for $[x]$ to mean the value of $x$ rounded down to the nearest integer?

No, I don't think so. It's elliptic curve (over finite field) scalar multiplication of a Generator. The result of the multiplication is a point. TBH, I don't think this is question is relevant to Math.SE (though the Q has been migrated here) - this is some notation particular to the book & would only probably be known to people familiar with Monero.

@user93353 In order for a question to be migrated it needs to be accepted by a moderator. We have no tag "[tag:notation]" back at Monero, but there's many here and nearly no bracket questions at Crypto. Though it's not impossible that it's particular to the author, they'd generally want to follow established conventions and such notation is used in another book where it's usage and background are explained in the prior text.
